# Image to memory slow

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I mostly would like advice..

My program displays multiple Large images on the screen.. 
Which are between 1-4 mbs each..
150 DPI, and 6000x4000 resolution, 24 bit depth..

I have many other settings which will give me smaller images.. but I need high qualitity images..

Ok, so It's slow.. but not that slow...
The only really bad part is when I switch from 1 image to the other..

So, I have basically 2 Images for every image.. 1 Thumb, and 1 HQ..
When the user zooms into an image I load the HQ, and when the user zooms out, it switches to the thumb image..

Right at that switching point, the user has to wait about 4-8 seconds for the HQ image to load into the memory and draw to the screen..

Below is the code I use when I load the HQ image

```
using (DrawingContext dc = ActiveImage.imageDV.RenderOpen())
                {
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(ActiveImage.imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Close();

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
    bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    //bitmap.Freeze();

    dc.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rect(ActiveImage.position, ActiveImage.size));
}
```

Below is the code I use when I load the Thumb image

```
using (DrawingContext dc = ActiveImage.imageDV.RenderOpen())
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(ActiveImage.thumbPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Close();

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bitmap, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
    bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    //bitmap.Freeze();

    dc.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rect(ActiveImage.position, ActiveImage.size));
}
```

Any way to optimize this? Is there some better way?
Remember I need a HQ crystal clear image only when the user is looking at a single image..

I suppose the MemoryStream could come out, but I added that as a kind of test..

Comment: Unrelated (possibly) to the question, but you might have some memory leaks in there with un-disposed memory streams. You should put them inside of usings like you are with the drawing context.

Comment: I would definitely try removing the extra memorystream and compare speed; not factoring in any loading optimization from disk/memory, you're doing the same copy step twice: once to memorystream, and again to transfer to bitmap.

Comment: And if you find the extra memorystream approach is more efficient, you can try Marshal.Copy to a byte array, then create the memory stream from that (random idea)

Comment: Quick note.. I the reason I added the memory stream in there was that.. If I load the image into the MS then to the bitmap, it allows me to edit the image file on the computer if I want.. If you go directly from filestream to bitmap, the image file is locked basically..

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but wouldn't it perhaps be the "best" solution to leave all potential optimization to WPF, and just load the image by its URI:

```
using (DrawingContext dc = ActiveImage.imageDV.RenderOpen())
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ActiveImage.imagePath));
    // alternatively, if it is a relative path
    // var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ActiveImage.imagePath, UriKind.Relative));

    dc.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rect(ActiveImage.position, ActiveImage.size));
}
```